# Using javascript to pass form fields' values to Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, url

I want to pass two inputs' values into url to make it like

"http://www.testing.com?item=product+amount=100"

It is just an example.

A lot of tutorials are passing values from url into fields of the form.

how to make it in a reverse way...

Thanks in advance.

P.S

There are two pages, one page has one form.
Page One's form is filling by users, and then pass the values through url to Page Two's form, Page Two's form can grab the values from the url to fill up the relatively fields.

Thank you so much for you guys' reply.

Comment: @JonasEverest `action` is the target page, I guess you'd mean `method="get"`. :P Also the default `method` is GET, so it isn't really necessary.

Comment: Please explain further what you are trying to do, as a form with the method GET will do this on it's own, and with ajax you can just use .serialize(). Either you are trying to do something else, or you did'nt search for other answers at all ?

Comment: I have provided more info..... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var data = $('input').serialize();
```

More specific can be:

```
var data = $('#item, #amount').serialize();
```

Then append the data to the querystring of the URL, or use one of jQuery ajax functions.

Answer (score 3):

Erm...

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="item" value="product" />
    <input type="text" name="amount" value="100" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When the submit button is clicked, the `item` and `amount` variables are "passed into the URL".

Comment: Couldn't they also be `type="hidden"`?